# SetRequestedOrientation does not exist when upgrading to Mono for Android 4.2

Tags: xamarin.android

I just upgraded to Mono for Android version 4.2. Since then I am getting an error when trying to call `SetRequestedOrientation` from an Activity. Just get an error that says it does not exist in the current context. I was using v4.0 and this was working fine.

Just wondering if anyone else is having this issue since upgrading or if you know of a fix. Thanks.

This code used to work fine.

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;

namespace AndroidApplication1
{
    [Activity(Label = "AndroidApplication1")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetRequestedOrientation(ScreenOrientation.Portrait);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's exposed through the [`RequestedOrientation`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=P:Android.App.Activity.RequestedOrientation) property.

```
RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
```